# C++ ifstream to function

Tags: c++

(french, sorry 4 bad english)
Hi guys,
I have an error when I want send ifstream to my function.

**function.cpp:**

```
void solo(ifstream fichier)
{
    fichier("dico.txt");
}
```

**function.h**

```
void solo(std::ifstream fichier);
```

[Error](http://prntscr.com/393l76)

Thank's !

Comment: Please post the error as a copied text, not as an external image.

Answer (score 5):

You're attempting to pass the stream by value, but streams cannot be copied. Pass by reference instead:

```
void solo(std::ifstream& fichier);
```